# How do I set attributes in an ActiveRecord Object before I save it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to understand the Active Record Callbacks, but they do not work, like I want to.

e.g.

Model

```
Checklist<ActiveRecord...
attr_accessible :item1, :item2, :done # they are all boolean

before_save :check_done

private
def check_done
  if item1 && item2
   write_attribute :done, true
  else
   write_attribute :done, false
  end
end
```

this doesn't work if I instantiate an object in the console and try to save it, the save operation returns "false" :(

What's wrong with this code?
thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:** It looks like there is something wrong with the "before_save" call, if I use "after_save", the code works...but the attribute isn't saved (obviously). That's really strange

**EDIT 2** Wierd...the development logs shows this

```
FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
[0m
  [1m[35mChecklist Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "checklists".* FROM "checklists" ORDER BY checklists.id DESC LIMIT 1
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id
```

but that is really odd, because if I remove the attr_accessible line I do still get this error...

**EDIT 3**
If anyone asks, yes I am trying to update an **existing** record.

**EDIT 4**
Yes, I like to edit
If I type in the console

```
c.save => # false
c.errors => #<OrderedHash {}>
```

Comment: Why do you mean by this doesn't work, what are the errors ? You can check by calling yourobject.errors after yourobject.save

Comment: oh, okay
I got this myobject.errors  #<OrderedHash {}>

Comment: How about `myobject.errors.inspect`??

Comment: this also returns => #<OrderedHash {}>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with your callback is that it returns `false` if either `item1` or `item2` is false.

From the [Active Record Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) documentation:

> If the returning value of a `before_validation` callback can be evaluated to `false`, the process will be aborted and `Base#save` will return `false`.

The solution is simple; return `true` at the end of your callback, like so:

```
def check_done
  self.done = (item1 && item2)
  return true
end
```

Comment: thankyou, thankyou, thankyou! BTW. to all of you if you are coming to Berlin, drop me a line, you earned a drink :)

Comment: This is really great, I started to lose sanity as I was trying to print/puts/p self at the end of the callback method and realized that doing so would return nil which would blow up the callback. sighs! Whew thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
before_save { |record|
  record.done = item1 && item2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PLease try:

```
def check_done
  if item1 && item2
    done = true
  else
    done = false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your private method, try

```
def check_done
  self.done = (self.item1 && self.item2) ? true : false
end
```

Comment: Buhuuu, that doesn't work either...but thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: Did you try by adding the self reference in @PeterWong solution?

Comment: Yours should be equivalent to mine...There should be other problems. @tabaluga, Does `item1`, `item2` set correctly (true and false as you expected). And is the column `done` is in boolean value? or would you mind adding some debug logs to see if the variables changes as you expected?

Comment: @PeterWong: I edited my post above, thanks. ActiveRecord points out "Can't Mass Assign these protected attributes". But if I remove the line attr_accessible the problem persist. And yes, all values are type boolean.

Comment: There's no need for the ternary here, `self.done = self.item1 && self.item2` would do fine.